# Variable value doesn't change, but I think it should

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that balances a checkbook. The input to the program should be a sequence of numbers representing checks and deposits. A negative number indicates a check and a positive number indicates a deposit. A zero signals the end of data. After each entry it should print the current balance.

I am able to get it to show the balance, and have it show the new balance, but when I type in the next number, it just goes back to the original balance. Here is my code:

```
package assignments;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Checkbook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter starting balance: ");
        double balance = keyboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Balance: $" + balance);

        for (int i = 0; i < balance; i++) 
        {

            System.out.print("Enter an amount - Zero wil quit the program: ");
            double amount = keyboard.nextInt();

            System.out.println();

            double newBalance = (balance+amount);   
            System.out.println("Balance: " + newBalance);

            if (amount == 0) 
            {
                System.out.println("Your ending balance is: " + newBalance);
                System.exit(i);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Here is an example of when I try to run it:

```
Enter starting balance: 500

Balance: $500.0
Enter an amount - Zero will quit the program: 260

Balance: 760.0
Enter an amount - Zero will quit the program: 20

Balance: 520.0
Enter an amount - Zero will quit the program:
```

It just goes back to the original balance. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I used `System.exit(i)`because I'm not sure how to make it stop without it. Here is an example of when I don't use it:

> Enter starting balance: 500
>
> ```
> Balance: $500.0
> Enter an amount - Zero will quit the program: 0
>
> Balance: 500.0
> Your ending balance is: 500.0
> Enter an amount - Zero will quit the program:
> ```

And with it:

```
Enter starting balance: 500

Balance: $500.0
Enter an amount - Zero will quit the program: 0

Balance: 500.0
Your ending balance is: 500.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you say

```
double newBalance = (balance+amount);
```

and never set `balance = newBalance`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of assigning the number to a new double assign it to the existing balance.  `newBalance` is a local variable and it gets overwritten in the loop during each iteration.  Storing the `balance` in the field or class instance variable balance will retain the value for each iteration of the loop.

```
balance = (balance+amount);
```

or

```
balance += amount;
```

Answer (score 2):

You write to `newBalance` all the time when you assign the value but read from `balance`... so the previous `newBalance` constantly gets replaced.

Answer (score 2):

You have set the local variable `newBalance`, but that value is lost on the next iteration.  Set `balance` to `newBalance` in the loop so that `balance` will change and reflect the correct balance.